# Using a service to track user state and getting $watch() to work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and am working on trying to develop a site with a NAV that is dependent on the user being logged in. I have decided to use a state model design with the Nav controller as the parent state of each of the pages.  This all works.

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');

$stateProvider
    .state('admin', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/Nav.html',
        controller: 'NavigationController'
    })
    .state('users', {
        url:'/users',
        templateUrl:'partials/Users.html',
        controller: 'UserController',
        parent: 'admin'
    })
    .state('devices', {
        url:'/devices',
        templateUrl:'partials/Devices.html',
        controller: 'DeviceController',
        parent: 'admin'
    }) ...
```

However, I need to track the state of the user and I thought I should use a Service to do this. So I have a service (`UserStatus`) that basically tracks the user's state (authenticated and username).  Other controllers communicate changes in these to this service. All works so far.

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('butler-user-status', []);

    app.service( 'UserStatusService', ['$http', function($http) {
        //
        // As a service, the 'this' when the code is called will likely point to other things.
        // To avoid this issue, I save 'this' in a local variable and then the functions can 
        // refer to that variable and it will always be the right one!
        //

        console.log('User Status: Initializing service...');
        var userStatusService = this;
        userStatusService.state = {currentUsername: '', 
                                    authenticated: false};


        $http.get('/currentUser', {})
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                // console.log('currentUser responded with data: '+JSON.stringify(data.username));
                if (data.username != null) {
                    console.log('UserStat: on success name='+data.username);
                    console.log('UserStat: on success authenticated='+true);
                };
            }).error(function(){
                // console.log('currentUser responded with error');
                console.log('UserStat: on error');
                userStatusService.state.currentUsername = '';
                userStatusService.state.authenticated = false;
            });

        this.login =  function(username) {
            console.log('Login: Setting username  and authenticated: username='+username);

            userStatusService.state.currentUsername = username;
            userStatusService.state.authenticated = true;

            console.log('Login: user logged in');
        };
        this.logout = function() { 
            userStatusService.state.authenticated = false; 
            console.log('Login: user logged out');
        };

    }]);
})();
```

Then I want to have the Nav controller track changes in the user status, so I set up a `$scope.$watch()` on a variable in the service and update variables in the controller when the service changed.  Then the HTML page could change its presentation by referencing the controller's variables.

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module('butler-navigation', ['butler-user-status']);

    app.controller('NavigationController', ['$scope', 'UserStatusService', function($scope, UserStatusService) {


        var navigationController = this;
        var isAuthenticated = UserStatusService.state.authenticated;
        var currentUsername = UserStatusService.state.currentUsername;

        console.log('Butler-Nav: at init: username ='+UserStatusService.state.currentUsername);
        console.log('Butler-Nav: at init: auth = '+ UserStatusService.state.authenticated);


        $scope.$watch('UserStatusService.state', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log('Butler-Nav: Updating isAuthenticated to:'+newValue+' from '+oldValue);
            navigationController.isAuthenticated = newValue;

        });


    }]);

})();
```

For some reason, I get an initial call-back to the `$watch` listener but with undefined for both the newValue and oldValue.  But I set the values in the service to real values, not null, etc.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for helping a newbie.

Comment: To avoid objections about the question being too broad or opinion based, please do show your current approach, and, if possible, ask how to achieve specific objectives.  (Personally I find your question to be clear and useful, but the close votes are already coming in...)

Comment: And I would change the title to something other than "best practices"

Comment: how can we possibly tell what's going wrong without seeing some code?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the code in question.  How do I get this question 'un-held'?

Comment: Where are you calling login function? Can you also post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that $watch evaluates expressions that are defined on the scope. Your UserStatusService isn't, so it is returning undefined. You have two options.

**Option 1**: Define a function the gets the state on the scope of NavigationController:

```
$scope.getUserState = function () {
    return UserStatusService.state;
};
```

You want to use a getter function here so it will always have the updated value. Then watch this expression:

```
$scope.$watch("getUserState()", function (newValue, oldValue) {
    // Do stuff on change here
});
```

This is a good option since you'll likely want this information available on the scope anyway so your UI can respond accordingly.

**Option 2**: You can always just watch the result of a function:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return UserStatusService.state;
}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    // Do stuff on change here
});
```

During each digest cycle, the first function will be evaluated and the result returned will be compared to the previous value. This is obviously simpler and avoids putting anything on the scope.

---

**Update with more explanation as requested**

You seem to be confused by normal JavaScript variable scope and what Angular calls the "scope".

Angular uses the word "scope" to refer to a special object that is available to expressions in the view. When you write something like "{{foo}}" in your view, Angular will populate that with the value of the variable named foo that is attached to the scope object. Scope objects are created by a number of directives and will be nested in each other. This nesting behavior is analogous to variable scoping, which is where the name comes from. [This page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) has more detail.

A controller has access to a scope object via the $scope variable that is injected by Angular. Anything you attach to the $scope variable will be accessible to the view for that controller. If you don't explicitly attach something to the $scope object it will not be accessible.

Now here's where the $watch function comes in. When you place an expression in a view (e.g. "{{foo}}"), Angular places a "watch" on the expression (in this case "foo"). When ever the user interacts with your application it triggers a digest loop. (There are other ways as well.) Angular will loop through all of the watched expressions, evaluate them, and see if they are different from the last time. Crucially for your question, these expressions only refer to variables on the scope. So you must attach something to the scope before this magic works. This is what my first option did.

Now my second option is a little more clever. Angular allows you to watch the result of a function. The whole digest loop process is the same, except instead of evaluating an expression on the scope, it evaluates your function.

[I made a fiddle to show this all works.](http://jsfiddle.net/dtjohnson/fm9825kn/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think I am still confused about what scope $watch() is using.  UserStatusService is a service so it is 'scope' once the initial creation occurs.  Your second solution seems to do precisely the same thing as I was trying to accomplish but somehow the UserStatusService is in scope in that function.  Can you help explain why these two approaches are different?

Comment: I added some more detail for you. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle and the explanation about Angular's scope.  I think I need to go back and re-visit some more basic Angular examples to get a better handle on when to use $scope, $this, etc.  Nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual answer, but my though on how you are solving this.

Is there any reason why you don't just expose the UserStatusService on the controller's scope and move your logic to the partials using directives?

I personally prefer exposing services into scope and leveraging on the directives, where angular has its greatest power.

Comment: I established the service since the user status exists across various controllers and I didn't want the user status to be lost as different controllers are instantiated, etc.

Comment: I got that Charlie. What I am suggesting is just assign the service on the scope, something like, $scope.userStatus = UserStatusService. Now you can use you service on your partials as you wish

Comment: Ok. I understand now. That could work but I prefer to isolate the partials to only use information from the controller. Sort of a separation of concerns preference.